# Javascript: toggle loading InnerHTML

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function toggle_table() {
        visibility = document.getElementById("table").style.visibility;
        document.getElementById("table").style.visibility = (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
        document.getElementById("toggle_table").innerHTML = (visibility == 'visible') ? 'Open' : 'Close';
    }
</script>

<form method='POST'>
    <a id='toggle_table' href='#' onClick='toggle_table()'>Open</a> WIJZIGEN PROCES
    <table id='table' style='visibility: hidden'>
    </table>
</form>
```

This works great. Though I don't want to just make it invisible, I want to not render the innerHTML (so it won't take it's space when invisible). Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694346/toggle-innerhtml), though I cannot make use of JQuery (requirements). Is this in a rather simple way with plain JavaScript, without the need of putting the whole HTML-content in Javascript?

Comment: use `display:none` to hide it from DOM, not visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display`:

```
document.getElementById("table").style.display = (display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right. This appears to be a CSS issue, not JS. Will accept as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` and `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden/visible`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using `display` property

```
function toggle_table() {
    display = document.getElementById("table").style.display;
    document.getElementById("table").style.display= (display != 'none') ? 'none' : 'table';
    document.getElementById("toggle_table").innerHTML = (display== 'table') ? 'Open' : 'Close';
}
```